# Как получить доступ к UI елементу из под потока?

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность, progress-bar

Есть в WPF поток который гоняет прогресс бар вперед назад

```
public static void Count(object _p)
    {
        ProgressBar p = (ProgressBar)_p;
        int i = 0;
        bool direction = true;
        for (; true; )
        {
            p.Value = i;
            if (direction)
            {
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                i--;
            }
            if (i == 100 || i==0)
            {
                direction = !direction;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
```

Вот его вызов

```
Thread loader_thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Count));
loader_thread.Start(progress);
```

Что я уже только не делал, не хочет программа записывать в ProgressBar значения и все.
Я пробовал разные способы,  но мне кажется что я делаю что-то не так

Comment: Научитесь работать с привязками, научитесь реализовывать MVVM. Сразу отпадут все проблемы!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Можно ссылочку почитать?

Comment: Чего то проверенного у меня нет, но допустим [вот](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.1.php). Суть довольно проста, разделите всю логику по своим местам (Model/View/ViewModel) и пишите приложение так, будто у вас вовсе нет View части, то есть обращаться к контролу напрямую по имени неверно, подписка на всякие события по типу Click тоже неверно, верно - создание свойств и к ним привязываться. Тут главное понять смысл и написать правильно хотя бы одно небольшое приложение и сразу тогда все встанет на свои места.